# Why is this image method returning a black image?

Tags: java, arrays

I am running the code below. What it is supposed to do is equalize an image passed into it. All the methods and variables run fine except for newPixelVal which is always zero. This then makes my image all black. I cannot figure out why this is returning 0.

```
public GImage equalize(GImage source) {
        // TODO
        int[][] pixelArray = source.getPixelArray();
        int[] luminousArray = new int[257]; 
        int[] cumulativeLuminousArray = new int[257]; 
        int height = pixelArray.length;
        int width = pixelArray[0].length;
        int k =-1;
        int luminosity =0;
        int l=0;
        int[][]equalizedArray = new int[height][width];
        int newRed = 0;
        int newGreen = 0; 
        int newBlue = 0;
        int newPixelVal = 0;
        int pixelsLessThan = 0;
        int v = 0;
        int totalPixels = height*width;
        for (int i=0; i<height; i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<width;j++) {
                int pixel=pixelArray[i][j];
                int red = (pixel>>16)& 0xFF;
                int green = (pixel>>8)&0xFF;
                int blue=pixel&0xFF;
                
                luminosity = computeLuminosity(red, green, blue);
                luminousArray[luminosity] = luminousArray[luminosity] +1;
                
                
    }}
    
        while(k<=256) {
            k++;
            l=k;
            while(l>=0&&k<=256) {
                cumulativeLuminousArray[k] = cumulativeLuminousArray[k]+luminousArray[l];
                l--;
                
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<height; i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<width;j++) {
                int pixel=pixelArray[i][j];
                int red = (pixel>>16)& 0xFF;
                int green = (pixel>>8)&0xFF;
                int blue=pixel&0xFF;
        
                luminosity = computeLuminosity(red, green, blue);
                v = luminosity-1; 
                pixelsLessThan=cumulativeLuminousArray[v];
                newPixelVal = 255*(pixelsLessThan/totalPixels);
                newRed= newPixelVal; 
                newBlue = newPixelVal; 
                newGreen = newPixelVal;
                int newPixel = (0xFF<<24)|(newRed<<16)|(newGreen<<8)|newBlue;
                equalizedArray[i][j]=newPixel;

                
            }
        }
        return new GImage(equalizedArray);
    }
```

Comment: When you declare the `newPixel` what is your intent here `(0xFF<<24)`, won't that just make the entire pixel transparent?

Comment: @sorifiend
No that will set the alpha value to the most opaque value. The trouble was with the fact two integers were divided at newPixelVal.

Comment: could You share details on the function computeLuminosity, it appears central but cannot see implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The division carried out at newPixelVal is between two int types. It will go to zero since the number of pixels less than is always less than total pixels. The decimal answer is truncated to 0. As soon as I replaced that with the line:

```
    newPixelVal = (int)(255*(float)pixelsLessThan/(float)totalPixels);
```

The calculation worked perfectly!